# List files in a blob storage container using spark activity in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I would like to know how to connect to and list what files are available in a blob storage container using an activity preferably pyspark in Azure Data Factory V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This python script allows access to the blobs via a pyspark script run using Azure Datafactory V2.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-python-quickstart/blob/master/example.py

However I had to use

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
```

instead of the suggested

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

Answer (score 1):

There a few ways which could help you:

> When you are using HDInsight Hadoop or Spark clusters in Azure, they are automatically pre-configured to access Azure Storage Blobs via the hadoop-azure module that implements the standard Hadoop FilesSystem interface. You can learn more about how HDInsight uses blob storage at **https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/**

A detailed guide can be found in this Blog post:[**https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/)

Another source which shows the integration of Storage API usage with Spark can be found in this **slide:https://www.slideshare.net/BrajaDas/azure-blob-storage-api-for-scala-and-spark**